# How do i get started with MEAN.IO?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean.io

Are there any good resources to get started with MEAN.IO? Any tutorials, todo Apps or books ? etc.,

Of course, I have visited the sites including [mean.io](http://mean.io/#!/), [mean.js](http://meanjs.org/), and some mean stack tutorials. But things little bit confusing for me to start.

Could any one please suggest me, For a good starting point with mean.io.

Thanks in advance.,

Comment: Exactly as with LAMP you should start studing the single blocks that are composing the stack.
So it's easier if you begin to study Express, Angular, Mongo one by one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really nice list of resources (MEAN Articles, Videos, Books, Podcasts) on Eric Douglas' github:
https://github.com/ericdouglas/MEAN-Learning

GL!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options to get started with MEAN stack. If you prefer free ones, you could take some courses from Microsoft Virtual Academy (MVA), MongoDb University and EDx.

Here are some MVA courses that could help you to jump start your development.

1. [MEAN Stack Jump Start](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/mean-stack-jump-start-8442) - introduces the stack
2. [Using Node.js with Visual Studio Code](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/using-nodejs-with-visual-studio-code-13920) - introduces node.js, Express, MongoDB
3. [Introduction to AngularJS](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/introduction-to-angularjs-8682) - Intro to Angular 1

Also there is a [course](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101JS/about) from vendor of MongoDB introducing the database as well as how to access it from node.js application.

In addition, there is an [advanced MEAN course](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-mongodb-using-mean-stack-mongodbx-m101x) from MongoDB vendor on EDx.

Moreover, one can find a lot of premium courses on [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/courses/) and [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/browse).

Good Luck!